# Visual Studio C# dynamic configuration names, no Debug or Release

Tags: dynamic, configuration, release

Suppose I do not have the standard configurations Debug or Release anymore.
Instead I have Production (Release configuration), Development (Debug configuration) and Test (Debug configuration) ... and and in the future other dynamic ones other names should be handeld in c# code.

Is there a way in C# to read the name of the configuration, even if they are dynamic?

```
#ifdef DYNAMIC_NAME???
// DYNAMIC_NAME code
#endif
```

will not work I suppose. Is there a solution for this problem available?